# Add Request Count As a Condition For Newrelic Alert

Tags: newrelic

Currently, I'm using the apm app metric's `apdex` to monitor the service's performance and trigger alerts. The conditions are created by `terraform`. But occasionally there are some alerts when the requests count is less than 10. How can I filter out these alerts by adding conditions(such as request count > 10), or do I have to increase the `T` in `apdex` for all applications? I saw the document(https://registry.terraform.io/providers/newrelic/newrelic/latest/docs/resources/alert_condition#terms) only supports the below conditions.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to use a NRQL condition instead where you can define `count > 10` in the filter of the query: https://registry.terraform.io/providers/newrelic/newrelic/latest/docs/resources/nrql_alert_condition

Eventually, all condition types are going to be converted to NRQL anyways per this post here: https://discuss.newrelic.com/t/big-news-for-alerts-and-applied-intelligence/161436#whats-going-away-3